# Find the number of unique items per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` `A` that looks like,

```
type    number    date 
1       1         2017-10-01
2       1         2017-10-31
1       2         2017-09-01
1       2         2017-08-01
2       2         2017-06-01
```

First I want to groupby `number` and select groups that each group need to at least contain 1 row with `type == 1` and one row with `type == 2`; in order to do that I first check that the sizes of each group must be > 2,

```
g = A.groupby('number')
B = g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1) # df B gets the filter results on g
```

but I don't know how to also check `type` values `1` and `2` are contained in every group acquired above.

Second, based on the groups acquired from step 1, I want to create a Boolean column in `A` called `type_2_before_type_1`, it is assigned `True` if earliest `date` for `type 1` substracts earliest `date` for `type 2` is < `0` for each group, and `False` otherwise. Since there could be many rows with `type == 1` and many rows with `type == 2` in each group (how to get `g['A'].transform('min')` for type 1 and type 2 rows?). So the result `df` `A` looks like,

```
type    number    date         type_2_before_type_1
1       1         2017-10-01   True
2       1         2017-10-31   True
1       2         2017-09-01   False
1       2         2017-08-01   False
2       2         2017-06-01   False
```

e.g. for the group with `number == 2`, earliest date for type 1 `2017-08-01` subtracts the earliest date for type 2 `2017-06-01`, result in 61 days; hence set `False` to `type_2_before_type_1`.

Comment: for example, in your number 2, if the the date is 2017-09-01 2017-02-01 2017-06-01 , what will be the result ?

Comment: @Wen for group with `number` == 2, it will set `True` to `type_2_before_type_1`, since `2017-02-01 - 2017-06-01 = -120 < 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, use `groupby` + `nunique` -

```
df.groupby('number').type.transform('nunique')

0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: type, dtype: int64

df = df[df.groupby('number').type.transform('nunique').gt(1)]

   type  number        date
0     1       1  2017-10-01
1     2       1  2017-10-31
2     1       2  2017-09-01
3     1       2  2017-08-01
4     2       2  2017-06-01
```

---

The second part is a bit challenging, but you can `groupby`, `unstack`, call `diff` and then get a mask -

```
df['type_2_before_type_1'] = \
 df.groupby(['number', 'type'])\
      .first()\
      .unstack()\
      .diff(-1, axis=1)\
      .iloc[:, 0]\
      .reindex(df.number)\
      .astype(int)\
      .lt(0)\
      .values

df

   type  number       date  type_2_before_type_1
0     1       1 2017-10-01                  True
1     2       1 2017-10-31                  True
2     1       2 2017-09-01                 False
3     1       2 2017-08-01                 False
4     2       2 2017-06-01                 False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g=df.groupby('number')
i=g.apply(lambda x : min(x['date'][x.type==1]))
j=g.apply(lambda x : min(x['date'][x.type==2]))
k=g.type.nunique()==2
df['New'] = df.number.map(~(i > j) & k)
df
Out[588]: 
   type  number       date    New
0     1       1 2017-10-01   True
1     2       1 2017-10-31   True
2     1       2 2017-09-01  False
3     1       2 2017-08-01  False
4     2       2 2017-06-01  False
```

Comment: Nice one, just need to invert the mask.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aha , you are right :-)I borrow the para name from you :-)

Comment: @Wen or just make `(i < j)` instead of `~(i > j)`?

Comment: @Wen there is a problem with this solution, i.e. for one group, it may not have type 1 or type 2, hence running `g.apply(lambda x : min(x['date'][x.type==1]))` and `g.apply(lambda x : min(x['date'][x.type==2]))` before making sure there are type 1 and 2 in each group may got `min() arg is an empty sequence` error? I should have pointed it out in the op, sry.